# want to speed up my code execution in python

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I am new to python and want to speed up code execution. Can someone help me out in increasing the performance of my code? code is given below:

```
def calcualte_edge_weight(df, r1, r2):

    data1 = df[df.reviewer_id == r1]
    data2 = df[df.reviewer_id == r2]
    
    products_r1 = set(data1.product_id)  # products set on which r1 write reviews
    products_r2 = set(data2.product_id)  # products set on which r2 write reviews
    products_common = products_r1.intersection(products_r2)
    
    total_weight = 0
    avg_score = 0
    for p in products_common:
        rating1 = data1[data1.product_id == p].rating.iloc[0]
        rating2 = data2[data2.product_id == p].rating.iloc[0]
        time1 = data1[data1.product_id == p].date.iloc[0]
        time2 = data2[data2.product_id == p].date.iloc[0]
        rd = abs( rating1 -  rating2)
        td = abs((dt.strptime(str(time1).strip(), '%m/%d/%Y') - dt.strptime(str(time2).strip(), '%m/%d/%Y')).days)
        if rd < 2 and td < 10:
            total_weight = total_weight + 1
        avg_score = total_weight/len(products_common)
    return avg_score
```

Comment: If you have working code that you want to improve, you might want to check if your question could be made [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for https://codereview.stackexchange.com. You should at least specify what the code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot of work to speedup your code, first of all, pandas iloc is not the fastest way to read a scalar from a Series.
Anyway i suggest to you to divide your code in pieces ad analize them. Divide and conquer is a good practice.
I suggest to use a tools for profiling.

I'm the developer of *[perf_tool](https://github.com/glaucouri/perf_tool)* that can be very usefull for these cases.

Comment: profiling shows that most of the time function takes in execution where  applying filter on dataframe. which is the fastest way to filter dataframe?

Comment: Better solutions here is to use *masks*, they works well and fast because are calculated in vectorial